# Video background with several files (library)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a video library (I want to use multiple files that will play in random order) as a background and can't find a way to do it in js

my html file includes this js script and I want the script to play multiple files, can't seem to find a way to do it.

```
// Video element
videoEl: document.querySelector('#background_video'),

// Container element
container: document.querySelector('body'),

// Resize
resize: true,

// autoplay: false,

isMobile: window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches,

playButton: document.querySelector('#play'),
pauseButton: document.querySelector('#pause'),

// Array of objects containing the src and type
// of different video formats to add
src: [
  {
    src: 'jews.mp4',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  },
  {
    src: 'jews.webm',
    type: 'video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'
  }
],
// What to do once video loads (initial frame)
onLoad: function () {
  document.querySelector('#video_cover').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried and what results that has produced please?

Comment: adding different sources in different ways etc
I'm not a coder